# JavaScript: rock paper scissors. Function error

Tags: javascript

im trying to create the game "rock, paper or scissors" in JavaScript, but im stuck on the last function "game()", it should repeat 5 times the function playRound() and throw a result each of those 5 times. But doesnt work.

```
function computerPlay(){
    let optionsList = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
    let option = optionsList[Math.floor(Math.random() * optionsList.length)];
    return option
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection){
    var playerSelection = prompt("Choose: rock, paper or scissors").toLowerCase();
    var computerSelection = computerPlay();

    if (playerSelection = "rock"){
        switch(computerSelection){
            case "rock":
                return "T";
            case "paper":
                return "M";
            case "scissors":
                return "Y";
        }
    }else if (playerSelection = "paper"){
        switch(computerSelection){
            case "rock":
                return "Y";
            case "paper":
                return "T";
            case "scissors":
                return "M";
        }
    }else if (playerSelection = "scissors"){
        switch(computerSelection){
            case "rock":
                return "M";
            case "paper":
                return "Y";
            case "scissors":
                return "T";
        }
    }
}

function game(){
    let i = 0
    for(i=1; i<=5; i++){
        playRound()
        if (playRound()= "M") {
            console.log("Machine Wins");
        }else if (playRound() = "Y"){
            console.log("You Win")
        }else if (playRound() = "T"){
            console.log("You Win!")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple errors:

- The first is that you are trying to use the `=` operator to compare values. You need to use `==` or `===`.
- Secondly, you need to get the return value of `playRound()` and then check its value to determine the outcome of the game. But instead, you are calling `playRound()` initially in each iteration of your loop, and then again each time you try to determine the outcome.

Try:

```js
function computerPlay() {
  let optionsList = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
  let option = optionsList[Math.floor(Math.random() * optionsList.length)];
  return option
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  var playerSelection = prompt("Choose: rock, paper or scissors").toLowerCase();
  var computerSelection = computerPlay();

  if (playerSelection === "rock") {
    switch (computerSelection) {
      case "rock":
        return "T";
      case "paper":
        return "M";
      case "scissors":
        return "Y";
    }
  } else if (playerSelection === "paper") {
    switch (computerSelection) {
      case "rock":
        return "Y";
      case "paper":
        return "T";
      case "scissors":
        return "M";
    }
  } else if (playerSelection === "scissors") {
    switch (computerSelection) {
      case "rock":
        return "M";
      case "paper":
        return "Y";
      case "scissors":
        return "T";
    }
  }
}

function game() {
  let i = 0
  for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    let outcome = playRound()
    if (outcome === "M") {
      console.log("Machine Wins");
    } else if (outcome === "Y") {
      console.log("You Win")
    } else if (outcome === "T") {
      console.log("You Win!")
    }
  }
}

game();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it this fixes the problem but here's a syntax error: = instead of ==. Also, you shouldn't call `playRound()` in every `else`. Just store the result in a variable.

```
 let result = playRound()
 if (result== "M") {                              
        console.log("Machine Wins");
 }else if (result == "Y"){
        console.log("You Win")             
 }else if (result == "T"){
        console.log("You Win!")
 }
```